# Altium 18 - "Override library primitive" option missing?

Tags: altium, software, setup

I'm busy setting up my new install of Altium 18 to match my preferred settings, namely making the default schematic font Consolas (for the purposes of mono spacing and slashed zeroes).

Normally this involves going into Tools -> Preferences -> Schematic -> Defaults screen, and changing all the fonts to the desired one for each primitive. However, since Altium 18 I notice the "override library primitive" checkbox for parameters/designators/values is missing, meaning while I get Consolas as the default font for any new schematic symbols I make, any existing library symbol I use still hangs on to Times New Roman.

**Old Altium:**

[image: Old]

**Altium 18:**
[image]

Any ideas where this checkbox went, or how to emulate the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha - Altium needed updating. This was only snuck back into Altium a few releases into version 18. Added as of release [18.1.0.16385](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ALEG/Release+Notes+for+the+Winter+09+Service+Pack+1+Release+of+Altium+Designer).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to have to disappoint you.

Checking that Box in AD18 will also cause EVERY part to take over the default designator value as well. So while this is fine if you place an IC which will get its U? as designator, placing a resistor will also give it a U? - basically rendering this option completely useless.

This is already being discussed in the Altium forums.

Comment: I literally just discovered this. Sigh. Insanity. Thanks for verifying that it wasn’t just me!

Answer (score 0):

Mine is still there, v18.1.6 Build 161. "All primitive default values are saved in the Advsch.dft and Advsch.MMsdft files. These files are located in the \Users\\AppData\Roaming\Altium\Altium Designer  folder of the installation."
Reload defaults to see if 'designator' shows up in Defaults list.
[image]